# System.Windows.Interactivity.dll loaded twice

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dll

I'm using in my application System.Windows.Interactivity.dll. I have specific version (3.0.40218.0) in my app's Program Files folder. 
This is the code responsible for loading it: 
`xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"`. 
Problem occurs when user has another version of this dll loaded in GAC_MSIL. Then for some reason both versions of this dll are loaded leading to crash. Is there any way I can choose specific version to be loaded?

Comment: why do you have specific version in app's Program Files folder?

Comment: You can use [Assembly Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions) in `app.config` to override versions.

Comment: @LeiYang System.Windows.Interactivity is part of Blend SDK. How else could it be shipped with application?

Comment: @BradleyUffner well I tried it, but problem is that it is actually C# dll for C++ application and it doesn't really work with app.config

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way I can choose specific version to be loaded?

No, the XAML parser will prevent you from using multiple versions of same assembly and trying to add the version number of the assembly to the namespace declaration in XAML will have no effect.

It is the reference that decides which assembly that is actually being loaded by the XAML parser. If you look in the project file (.csproj), you should be able to see which version of the assembly that you have referenced.

Comment: Thanks for answer I figured it out. Anyway it seems interesting that despite the fact that some particular version was chosen, when not found the newer  one was loaded. Looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems that I found the issue. I think it might be bug in .NET. In "References" I had old version of file (for .NET 4.0). If it was cached of course it was loaded, but for some reason also the new dll (for .NET 4.5), that is present in my application's Program Files folder was cached in GAC_MSIL and also loaded. So my conslusion is that it accidentally worked with only new version present. Hope it helps someone with similar issue.